# Using cxfreeze to convert python source to frozen binary

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a python script into a stand alone executable. I was originally going to use py2exe but it does not support python 3 yet. I downloaded cx_freeze and installed it, but I get a cxfreeze is not a recognized command when trying to convert the file. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include the path in system environment variables. To do this I went into the control panel, then system, then into the advanced tab and clicked on the environment variables. Then edited the path variable to include a path to the cx_freeze executable.